# Timedelta error; version 0.15.1-=np19py27_0

Tags: pandas, timedelta

This problem was asked at:

[pandas Timedelta error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15149265/pandas-timedelta-error)

However, the solution (to get the latest version of pandas) did not work for me.

I've got the same problem (installed using anaconda, on Windows 7), and trying to do this gets the same problem.

Running from ipython:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
-----------------------------------------
ImportError
<ipython-input-1-af55e7023913> in <module
----> 1 import pandas as pd

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\__in
     45
     46 # let init-time option registrati
---> 47 import pandas.core.config_init
     48
     49 from pandas.core.api import *

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core
     15                                 i
     16                                 g
---> 17 from pandas.core.format import de
     18
     19

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core
      7 from pandas.core.base import Pand
      8 from pandas.core.common import ad
----> 9 from pandas.core.index import Ind
     10 from pandas import compat
     11 from pandas.compat import(StringI

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core
     13 import pandas.algos as _algos
     14 import pandas.index as _index
---> 15 from pandas.lib import Timestamp,
     16 from pandas.core.base import Pand
     17 from pandas.util.decorators impor

ImportError: cannot import name Timedelta
```

I've checked the pandas version, it is 0.15.1-np19py27_0.

nosetests pandas also returns problems:

```
PS R:\data\python_testing\ipython_notebooks> nosetests pandas
E
======================================================================
ERROR: Failure: ImportError (cannot import name Timedelta)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\nose\loader.py", line 403, in loadTestsFromName
    module = resolve_name(addr.module)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\nose\util.py", line 311, in resolve_name
    module = __import__('.'.join(parts_copy))
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
    import pandas.core.config_init
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\config_init.py", line 17, in <module>
    from pandas.core.format import detect_console_encoding
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\format.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pandas.core.index import Index, MultiIndex, _ensure_index
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\index.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pandas.lib import Timestamp, Timedelta, is_datetime_array
ImportError: cannot import name Timedelta

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

This issue is discussed at github:

https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/8862

Comment: issue persists with pandas: 0.15.2-np19py27_0

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem recently, and it turned out to be because I had recently used conda to install some packages from the command prompt, but had forgetten to launch the command prompt as administrator.

In my case I was able to fix the problem by launching command prompt as administrator, and reinstalling the packages concerned with "conda install -f ".

In your case you could try "conda install -f pandas".
It is possible you might have this problem with more than one package.

Comment: Re-installing pandas in an admin command prompt fixed this issue for me. thanks

Answer (score 1):

i'm pretty sure this issue occurs on Windows due to file open issues. Because a process is holding the file handler to one of the packages files the upgrade fails. Kill all Python and Excel processes and try again.